Checkmarx flagging JPA repository method with @Query annotation as possible stored XSS attack
I have a jpa repository with a method similar to:
@Query("select distinct concat(p.firstName, ' ', p.lastName) as name from PersonEntity p")
public String[] findDistinctNames();

I'm using checkmarx in my pipeline and it flags the use of this (and any similar non-parameterized methods with @Query) as being at risk of a stored XSS attack. For example, in my service class, using the method like:
// MyService.java
public String[] findDistinctNames() {
    return personRepository.findDistinctNames();
}

Will result in checkmarx flagging the repository method.
I've tried escaping the returned values with StringEscapeUtils::escapeHtml4, but checkmarx is flagging the method itself, so no amount of post santitization stops it from being flagged.
I've read that non-parameterized queries are a danger, but in this case I'm not sure what I can do. I can't omit the @Query portion because of the need for the concat procedure.
So, is there another way I could go about this, or is this simply a false positive from checkmarx?

I don't know any details of checkmarx, but its complaint is ridiculous --  enough so that I am inclined to guess that either you are using the tool incorrectly, or else that it simply is not well suited for analyzing JavaEE code, and maybe not Java code in general.  Its diagnostic is definitely a false positive.

@JohnBollinger That's what I'm assuming as well. I can't seem to find any fix that works, so my guess is that it's a false positive with checkmarx.
